# Express session not starting

Tags: node.js, express-session

My page is supposed to be redirected after the login. But it just keeps loading without showing any error message, and without redirecting to /profile. I checked express documentation but the problem seems to be with my code and not with express-session?

````
app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
        path: '/auth'   ,
    secure: false,
        maxAge  : 24*60*60*1000,
        ephemeral: true
  },
}));

const login = async (req, res, next) => {

  //req body
  try {
    //querying the database 

    //find email

    if (results && results.length && user.email_address) {
      req.session.loggedin = true;
      req.session.email_address = email_address;
      req.session.save();
      return res.redirect('/profile');

    //check if password matches 

  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send({ success: false, message: 'Server error' });
  }

  await next;
}

const requiresLogin = async (req, res, next) => {
      if (req.session.loggedin && req.session.email_address) {
        return next();
      } else {
        return res.status(401).send('You must be logged in to view this page');
      }
  }
routes.js :

mainRouter.post('/auth', login)
mainRouter.get('/profile', requiresLogin);```
````

Answer (score 0):

I see syntax error in your code. See the if block in login function. You did not close if block. Also, I believe you should change `await next` to `next()`;

Comment: Hi, no that's not it, also the login is functioning properly.

Comment: @oneone did you notice any unhandledPromiseRejection in your console?

Comment: The page just keeps loading and that's it